# Как проитерировать объект с помощью forEach, если он похож на итерируемый, но таковым не является?

Tags: javascript

Существует объект:

```
let obj = {
1: {name: "name1", value: 123},
2: {name: "name1", value: 456}
}
```

Он похож на итерируемый объект, но таковым не является, ведь так?
Я сделал вывод, что объект `obj` неитерируемый после того, как применил к нему метод `Array.from`

```js
let obj = {
1: {name: "name1", value: 123},
2: {name: "name1", value: 456}
}

let arr = Array.from(obj);

console.log(obj);
console.log(arr);
```

Мне нужно перебрать циклом forEach объект `obj`, например, так:

```js
let obj = {
  1: {name: "name1", value: 123},
  2: {name: "name1", value: 456}
};

obj.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.name);
});
```

И даже так пробую:

```js
let obj = {
  1: {name: "name1", value: 123},
  2: {name: "name1", value: 456}
};

[].forEach.call(obj, function(element) {
  console.log(element.name);
});
```

Безрезультатно.

Вопрос в том, каким образом можно привести объект `obj` к такому виду:
`[{name: "name1", value: 123}, {name: "name1", value: 456}]` или как его перебрать с помощью forEach?

Comment: а сами значения индексов `1` и `2`  важны?

Comment: а как на счёт for...in ?

Comment: @Grundy, смысл в том, что ключи будут 1, 2, 3 и тд в зависимости от количества элементов, из БД такой объект приходит

Comment: @freestyle_HD, тебе они нужны для дальнейшей работы?

Comment: @Grundy, нет, эти индексы мне не нужны.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, думал об этом, просто стало интересно, почему не получается с помощью forEach сделать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы сделать объект `array-like`, ему нужно добавить свойство `length`, значение которого должно быть больше любого целочисленного индекса в объекте.

```js
let obj = {
  1: {
    name: "name1",
    value: 123
  },
  2: {
    name: "name1",
    value: 456
  },
  length: 3
}

let arr = Array.from(obj);

[].forEach.call(obj, function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});
console.log(arr);
```

Кроме того, если исходные индексы не важны, можно воспользоваться методом [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
let obj = {
  1: {
    name: "name1",
    value: 123
  },
  2: {
    name: "name1",
    value: 456
  }
}

Object.values(obj).forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

А также, никто не отменял обычный [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) позволяющий перебирать ключи объекта

```js
let obj = {
  1: {
    name: "name1",
    value: 123
  },
  2: {
    name: "name1",
    value: 456
  }
}

for (var key in obj) {
  var element = obj[key];
  console.log(element);
};
```